# PHP assignment help code wont work

Tags: php, html

```
<body>
    <form id= "form1" name="assignment5" action= "assignment.php" method="POST">
        <div class="elements">
            <label>Company Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="cname" placeholder="Company Name"/>
        </div>

        <div class="elements">
            <label>Owner:</label>
            <input type="text" name="owner" placeholder="Owner"/>
        </div>

        <div class="elements">
            <label>Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address"/>
        </div>

        <div class="elements">
            <label>Phone Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
        </div>

        <div class="elements">
            <label>Annual Sales:</label>
            <input type="number" name="annualsales"/>
        </div>
        <div class="elements">
            <label>Borrow Amount: </label>
            <input type="number" name="borrowamount"/>
        </div>

        <div class="elements">
            <label>Payment Terms: </label>
            <input type="number" name="paymentterms"/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset Fields"/>
        <input type="submit">   
    </form>
    <br>
</body>
```

---

1. PhP : the file name is indeed assignment5 and its in the same folder, and sitll cant get the code to work.

---

```
<body>
<?php
    $companyname=$_POST['cname'];
    $annualsales=$_POST['annualsales'];
    $borrowamount=$_POST['borrowamount'];
    $paymentterms=$_POST['paymentterms'];
    $interest=($borrowamount*($paymentterms/12))*0.03;
    $payment = $borrowamount+ $interest;
    $profit = $payment-$borrow;
?>
<table> 
    <tr>
        <th> Company name </th>
        <th> Annual Sales </th>
        <th> Borrow Amount </th>
        <th> Payment Terms </th>
        <th> Total Interest </th>
        <th> Total Payment </th>
        <th> Profit </th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo "$_POST['cname']" ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo "$annualsales" ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo "$borrowamount" ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo "$paymentterms" ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo "$interest" ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo "$payment" ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo "$profit" ?> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Why wont this work?
it needs to output the input that is received in form, in the correct place in the table that is created in the .php file. As of now, it doesnt output anything where it should be outputting the variables content.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the problem. "Doesn't work" is almost meaningless. Describe what it *should* be doing as well as what it *is* doing.

Comment: it needs to output the input that is received in form, in the correct place in the table that is created in the .php file. As of now, it doesnt output anything where it should be outputting the variables content.

Comment: In addition to the above suggestion, please attempt proper indentation and formatting. This often helps with diagnosing problems.

Comment: Keep in mind `echo "$x"` is equivalent to `echo $x` and the latter is far simpler, so do that unless you need to add other things to your string.

Comment: What errors are you seeing? What behavior are you seeing? We cannot see your screen, so we need to know what's happening in order to make suggestions.

Comment: Do you actually have a complete HTML document or is this all the HTML in these files

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have the complete html document, but i just copy pasted the body thats it.

Comment: php : https://pastebin.com/8j8uu1dJ
 main : https://pastebin.com/M7rcD4Vk

Comment: What is tha actual and full file name of the second piece of code containing the PHP Script?

Comment: @RiggsFolly assignment.php

Comment: And you are running this through a web server right? Not just double clicking on a file manager like you might for an exe file??

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, running through a web server

Comment: Start by letting PHP tell you if it encounter issues: Put `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the very top of your `.php` file.

Comment: _" it doesnt output anything where it should be outputting"_ Does this mean that it _is_ outputting the data, but just in the wrong place? Is it all over the document, just in the wrong order in that table row or is the table outputted correctly but in the wrong place in the document?

Answer (score 0):

there are a few issues in your code

in the form the `action` is incorrect it should be 
`action="assignment5.php";`

in your assignment5.php file there are several issues

where you assign the variable `$profit` it should look like this

```
 $profit = $payment-$borrow;
```

the line where you echo the post variable `$_POST['cname']` should look like this

```
<td> <?php echo $_POST['cname'] ?> </td>
```

the issue here was that it will not pass 'cname' to the array and give an un-terminated white space error.

otherwise I've tested this code and it works.